# Trying to use stripe.js with rails, can't figure it out

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to follow this to set up stripe. There's a pretty good checkout guide that's rails specific: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails

However, I can't find a similar guide for using stripe.js instead (since I want my own custom form. I'm having trouble implementing stripe and the only guide I found is this https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form which doesn't work well with rails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here below a quick *how-to* based on my experience (you can find my dummy Rails-Stripe integration [here](https://github.com/davideghz/stripe_rails)):

First of all, add `gem 'stripe'` to your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` and restart your webserver.

Create `charges_controller.rb` add `charge_customform` action:

```
def charge_customform
    # Amount in cents
    @amount = 99

    # Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:email],
        :source  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    # Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    begin
      Stripe::Charge.create(
          :amount => @amount,
          :currency => 'usd',
          :customer => customer.id,
          :description => 'Example charge custom form'
      )
      redirect_to charges_thanks_path
      # remember to create a thanks.html.erb page in view/charges :)

      rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to root_path
    end

end
```

In your view, first of all import the required JS in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

Then set your publishable key

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('your_key_here');
</script>
```

Add your custom form_tag:

```
<%= form_tag charge_customform_charges_path, id: 'payment-form' do %>
  <span class="payment-errors"></span>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>
      <span>Your email</span>
      <input value="<%= current_user.email if current_user %>" type="text" size="20" data-stripe="email">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>
      <span>Card Number</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>
      <span>Expiration (MM/YY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month">
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_year">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>
      <span>CVC</span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc">
    </label>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Payment">
<% end %>
```

And finally add the JS to call Stripe's API and handle the response with the token:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var $form = $('#payment-form');
    $form.submit(function(event) {
      // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
      $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);
      // Request a token from Stripe:
      Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
      // Prevent the form from being submitted:
      return false;
    });
  });
  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    // Grab the form:
    var $form = $('#payment-form');
    if (response.error) { // Problem!
      // Show the errors on the form:
      $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
      $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission
    } else { // Token was created!
      // Get the token ID:
      var token = response.id;
      // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
      $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token));
      // Submit the form:
      $form.get(0).submit();
    }
  };
</script>
```

**EDIT**

In my first answer I mentioned [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe?autoplay=true) which explain how to setup plans and subscriptions with custom forms. Still a good base, but maybe not 100% pertinent with the question.

Comment: I did look at that railscasts! But it had plans and subscriptions and I wasn't sure if I needed that much... unless it's required for stripe.

Comment: no, plans and subscriptions are not required if you do not need them! I forgot that tutorial refers to subscriptions. For single one-time charges you can refer to the code I posted in the answer, above all check the code in `charges_controller.rb`

Comment: okay, thanks! Quick question, this part `Stripe.setPublishableKey('your_key_here')` seems like I would need to put my key right onto my website. Is that safe? Also, stripe gives two keys, what do I do with the secret key?

Comment: and to clarify, the only controller I would need to add would be charges?

Comment: In my implementation I hardcoded my publishable key. It's not the best practice but it's a public key so it shouldn't be a big concern. To be 100% safe you can put it in an ENV variable (check Figaro gem to do this on local). Yes, you need to create the charges_controller.rb and add the action I wrote in my answer!

Comment: thank you. Last question, why did you create your own action charge_customform instead of just using the create action?

Comment: good question. I copied the code from a repo (link in the answer) where I tested several integrations with Stripe (checkout.js, customform, recurring customer), and the standard create action was used by the checkout.js integration :) - note that the code is very similar... I guess I will refactor it soon!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120373/discussion-between-nachime-and-davideghz).

Comment: I have been banging my head against my desk all day trying to get this working. Literally 10 different tutorials. And it was this one that finally did it, at 11:19pm. THANK YOU!! (I know, I'm not supposed to use this box for thanks, but seriously, what a day, thank you so much...)